# Error leyendo CSV file

Tags: android-studio, csv, kotlin, tokens

Estoy trabajando en un programa y dispongo de 2 funciones que leen archivos tipo CSV desde los recursos, los datos de estos se separan por ; lo curioso es que la estructura de ambas (fun) es la misma, pero del código de la segunda, que anexo mas abajo me muestra el siguiente error

Error mostrado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

archivo CSV

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

open class Productos(var id: String?, var descripcion: String?, var precio: String?) {

```
override fun toString(): String {
    return "Productos [id = $id, descripcion = $descripcion, precio = $precio]"
}
```

private fun cargar_productos(){

```
    val PRODUCT_ID = 0
    val PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION = 1
    val PRODUCT_PRICE = 2

    var fileReader: BufferedReader? = null

    try {
        val products = ArrayList<Productos>()
        val inputStreamProducts:InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.productos)
        val fileReaderProducts: BufferedReader
        fileReaderProducts = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStreamProducts))

        //Leer el encabezado del archivo CSV
        fileReaderProducts.readLine()

        //Leer el resto del archivo
        var line = fileReaderProducts.readLine()
        while (line != null){
            val tokens = line.split(";")
            if (tokens.isNotEmpty()){
                val product = Productos(
                    tokens[PRODUCT_ID],
                    tokens[PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION],
                    tokens[PRODUCT_PRICE])//linea de error kt:242
                products.add(product)
            }
            line = fileReaderProducts
                .readLine()
        }
        // Print the new customer list
        for (product in products) {
            println(product)
        }
    }catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Error leyendo CSV!")
        e.printStackTrace()
    } finally {
        try {
            fileReader?.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            println("Closing fileReader Error!")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

al tratarse de números intente usar Integer.parseInt(tokens[PRODUCT_PRICE])) pero nada, luego decidí tratarlo como un String? desde la clase Productos y cambialo a un tokens[PRODUCT_PRICE]) pero tampoco, usar tokens[PRODUCT_PRICE]).toString y nada, tambien tokens["$PRODUCT_PRICE"] me pide que tiene que ser Int osea tampoco, alguna idea de porque falla siendo igual a la otra función

Comment: ¿Sería porque no evaluas los espacios entre las palabras dentro de la token[Product Description]?

Answer (score 0):

encontre el problema de lectura, y radica en que el archivo CSV esta mal guardado
en lugar de ser un solo producto

ejm;descripcion de ejemplo;3.000

esta separado debido al largo y provocando error

ejm;descripcion de

ejemplo;3.
000

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas dando una solución a la pregunta planteada?

Comment: encontré el problema y quizá a alguien le sirva la solución :)